# Laravel eloquent relationships with pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hello I have two models User and Car and a pivot table user_car which has two columns user_id and car_id, the combination of the two columns is always unique. Any user can have many cars and one car is assigned to only one user

In the User model I have this

```
public function cars()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Car', 'user_car');
}
```

In the Car model I have this

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        'App\User', 'user_car', 'car_id', 'user_id'
    );
}


$user->cars
```

returns all the cars for the user as collection which is fine, but I want

```
$car->user
```

returns also collection which is only one user. I do not want collection, I want for example to get the user id like this

```
$car->user->id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use laravel default naming convention like alphabetically `car_user` so that you can follow along. Also it's not a many to many relationship as you've stated in your case it's a one to many relationship. A many to many relationship example something like `an author can have many books published and a book can have many authors behind it` so in a database table it would be like `author_id` and `book_id` in a table

Author_Id | book_id |

1                 2

1                 1

so in your case it would be like

```
class User {
public function cars()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Car');
}
}
```

make sure you have `user_id` field in your cars table
and in your Car

```
class Car{
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
}
```

so that you can query it up like

```
$user = User::first();
$user->car->car_name ;
```

or when you start w/ car

```
// to pluck the specific car
$car = Car::find(3); 
$car->user->full_name  or owner depends upon you
```